# using qtip in xpages

Tags: xpages, qtip

i'm trying to display qtip2 for certain xpage Components. To make it generic, i have created a custom control which has (fieldID & componentID as custom properties). i have a view which has all fieldID's and associated help text for each id ( which is unique)

My problem is that i'm unable to call a SSJS function from CSJS with input parameters. Please see my code below. if i hardcode fieldID (getFieldHelp('"+fieldID+"')) everything works fine but when i pass variable it will return null value. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

**script block**

```
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2"
    value="var fieldID=#{compositeData.fieldID};var componentID=#{compositeData.componentID};">
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

**on client load event**

```
   alert(componentID+"~~~~~~~~~~~"+fieldID)
   var helpContent="#{javascript:getFieldHelp('"+fieldID+"')}"
   alert(helpContent)
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     x$("#{id:link_Test}").qtip({           
     //x$(compid).qtip({
         content: "helpContent",        
         style: 'qtip-tipsy qtip-shadow'

      });


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. If you want to send a ClientSide variable 'fieldID' to a SSJS (getFieldHelp) you have to use something like the ExecuteOnServer function from [Jeremy Hodge.](http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC) because you have to POST this variable to the Server.

But why dont you use:

```
var helpContent ="#{javascript:getFieldHelp(compositeData.fieldID)}"
```

assuming that getFieldHelp is a SSJS function and both code snippets are in the same component. =)
(maby you have to Change the # to $ to get the compositeData.)

**update:**
I did some testing on getting the compositeData.FieldID in an CSJS onClientLoad event.
What i came up with is this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            alert("#{javascript:return compositeData.fieldId}");
            });]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

I use the `XSP.addOnLoad()` to execute the CSJS (onClientLoad) and inside the `xp:scriptBlock` i can pass the compositeData to the client side.

Comment: Thank you Michael. When i added my code in XSP.addOnLoad everything was working fine. Thanks once again. out of curiosity, what is the diff between "#" & "$" to get compositeData

Comment: You're welcome. To your question: If you open your Code window for SSJS you can select dynamical or on page load. # stands for the dynamical and $ for the onPageLoad.